# Scroll bar cutting the rounded edges

Tags: html, css

I've a div and it has a scroll bar added to it. My HTML for div is as below.

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
  <div class="chat-box-new-div">
    <div class="chat-box-new-head">Frequently Asked Questions ..
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body chat-box-new">
      <ul class="questionsUl">
        <li>Who is a public official?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>My client asked if her son can intern with the company as a favor to her, that isn't a problem is it?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>My friend works for the client, does that mean I can't give her a gift?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Is there certain criteria for gifts and entertainment&nbsp;</li>
        <li>How do I know if Gift or Entertainment is permissible?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>can I give gift cards to my team?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Do I need approval to give a gift?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Are Facilitating Payments” to Public Officials allowed?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>is there approval needed for gifts to public officials?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Who is a public official?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>My client asked if her son can intern with the company as a favor to her, that isn't a problem is it?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>My friend works for the client, does that mean I can't give her a gift?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Is there certain criteria for gifts and entertainment&nbsp;</li>
        <li>How do I know if Gift or Entertainment is permissible?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>can I give gift cards to my team?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Do I need approval to give a gift?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Are Facilitating Payments” to Public Officials allowed?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>is there approval needed for gifts to public officials?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Who is a public official?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>My client asked if her son can intern with the company as a favor to her, that isn't a problem is it?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>My friend works for the client, does that mean I can't give her a gift?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Is there certain criteria for gifts and entertainment&nbsp;</li>
        <li>How do I know if Gift or Entertainment is permissible?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>can I give gift cards to my team?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Do I need approval to give a gift?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Are Facilitating Payments” to Public Officials allowed?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>is there approval needed for gifts to public officials?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Who is a public official?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>My client asked if her son can intern with the company as a favor to her, that isn't a problem is it?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>My friend works for the client, does that mean I can't give her a gift?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Is there certain criteria for gifts and entertainment&nbsp;</li>
        <li>How do I know if Gift or Entertainment is permissible?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>can I give gift cards to my team?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Do I need approval to give a gift?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Are Facilitating Payments” to Public Officials allowed?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>is there approval needed for gifts to public officials?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Who is a public official?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>My client asked if her son can intern with the company as a favor to her, that isn't a problem is it?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>My friend works for the client, does that mean I can't give her a gift?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Is there certain criteria for gifts and entertainment&nbsp;</li>
        <li>How do I know if Gift or Entertainment is permissible?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>can I give gift cards to my team?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Do I need approval to give a gift?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Are Facilitating Payments” to Public Officials allowed?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>is there approval needed for gifts to public officials?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Who is a public official?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>My client asked if her son can intern with the company as a favor to her, that isn't a problem is it?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>My friend works for the client, does that mean I can't give her a gift?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Is there certain criteria for gifts and entertainment&nbsp;</li>
        <li>How do I know if Gift or Entertainment is permissible?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>can I give gift cards to my team?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Do I need approval to give a gift?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Are Facilitating Payments” to Public Officials allowed?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>is there approval needed for gifts to public officials?&nbsp;</li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The issue that I'm facing is there is a scroll bar created, and when the edges were straight there was no issues. I've made the edges rounded, And the scroll bar goes out of the bottom.

Here is a working fiddle that I've created https://jsfiddle.net/cp751fu5/

please let me know how can I fix this.

Thanks

Comment: You are using overflow:hidden rule so scroll bar can not go out of the bottom. Please check it again.

Comment: I advise you to make the border bottom less or minimum. It won't solve your problem but will  make it look nicer.

Comment: Give overflow:relative to your .chat-box-new-div. You can get the idea then what to change.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give some padding  to .chat-box-new-div

Answer (score 0):

change the code as follows add line to .chat-box-new-div:

`padding: 0 0 37px;`

(Tested on fiddle)

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Just Add `padding-bottom:35px;` like below

```
.chat-box-new-div {
  height: 502px;
  border: 2px solid #157DEC;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #157DEC;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 3.4em;
  padding-bottom:35px;
}
```

**Demo**

```css
@media (min-width: 1200px) .col-lg-3 {
  width: 25%;
}

.chat-box-new-div {
  height: 502px;
  border: 2px solid #157DEC;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #157DEC;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 3.4em;
  padding-bottom:35px;
}

.chat-box-new-head {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #157DEC;
  background-color: #157DEC;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-top-left-radius: 4em;
  border-top-right-radius: 4em;
}

.chat-box-new {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 461px;
}

.questionsUl {
  margin-left: -20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
  <div class="chat-box-new-div">
    <div class="chat-box-new-head">Frequently Asked Questions ..
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body chat-box-new">
      <ul class="questionsUl">
        <li>Who is a public official?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>My client asked if her son can intern with the company as a favor to her, that isn't a problem is it?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>My friend works for the client, does that mean I can't give her a gift?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Is there certain criteria for gifts and entertainment&nbsp;</li>
        <li>How do I know if Gift or Entertainment is permissible?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>can I give gift cards to my team?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Do I need approval to give a gift?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Are Facilitating Payments” to Public Officials allowed?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>is there approval needed for gifts to public officials?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Who is a public official?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>My client asked if her son can intern with the company as a favor to her, that isn't a problem is it?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>My friend works for the client, does that mean I can't give her a gift?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Is there certain criteria for gifts and entertainment&nbsp;</li>
        <li>How do I know if Gift or Entertainment is permissible?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>can I give gift cards to my team?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Do I need approval to give a gift?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Are Facilitating Payments” to Public Officials allowed?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>is there approval needed for gifts to public officials?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Who is a public official?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>My client asked if her son can intern with the company as a favor to her, that isn't a problem is it?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>My friend works for the client, does that mean I can't give her a gift?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Is there certain criteria for gifts and entertainment&nbsp;</li>
        <li>How do I know if Gift or Entertainment is permissible?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>can I give gift cards to my team?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Do I need approval to give a gift?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Are Facilitating Payments” to Public Officials allowed?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>is there approval needed for gifts to public officials?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Who is a public official?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>My client asked if her son can intern with the company as a favor to her, that isn't a problem is it?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>My friend works for the client, does that mean I can't give her a gift?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Is there certain criteria for gifts and entertainment&nbsp;</li>
        <li>How do I know if Gift or Entertainment is permissible?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>can I give gift cards to my team?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Do I need approval to give a gift?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Are Facilitating Payments” to Public Officials allowed?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>is there approval needed for gifts to public officials?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Who is a public official?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>My client asked if her son can intern with the company as a favor to her, that isn't a problem is it?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>My friend works for the client, does that mean I can't give her a gift?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Is there certain criteria for gifts and entertainment&nbsp;</li>
        <li>How do I know if Gift or Entertainment is permissible?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>can I give gift cards to my team?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Do I need approval to give a gift?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Are Facilitating Payments” to Public Officials allowed?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>is there approval needed for gifts to public officials?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Who is a public official?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>My client asked if her son can intern with the company as a favor to her, that isn't a problem is it?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>My friend works for the client, does that mean I can't give her a gift?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Is there certain criteria for gifts and entertainment&nbsp;</li>
        <li>How do I know if Gift or Entertainment is permissible?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>can I give gift cards to my team?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Do I need approval to give a gift?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Are Facilitating Payments” to Public Officials allowed?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>is there approval needed for gifts to public officials?&nbsp;</li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the bottom padding in `.chat-box-new-div` class

```
.chat-box-new-div {
  height: 502px;
  border: 2px solid #157DEC;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #157DEC;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 3.4em;
  padding-bottom:30px;
}
```

```css
@media (min-width: 1200px) .col-lg-3 {
  width: 25%;
}

.chat-box-new-div {
  height: 502px;
  border: 2px solid #157DEC;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #157DEC;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 3.4em;
  padding-bottom:30px;
}

.chat-box-new-head {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #157DEC;
  background-color: #157DEC;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-top-left-radius: 4em;
  border-top-right-radius: 4em;
}

.chat-box-new {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 461px;
}

.questionsUl {
  margin-left: -20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
  <div class="chat-box-new-div">
    <div class="chat-box-new-head">Frequently Asked Questions ..
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body chat-box-new">
      <ul class="questionsUl">
        <li>Who is a public official?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>My client asked if her son can intern with the company as a favor to her, that isn't a problem is it?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>My friend works for the client, does that mean I can't give her a gift?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Is there certain criteria for gifts and entertainment&nbsp;</li>
        <li>How do I know if Gift or Entertainment is permissible?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>can I give gift cards to my team?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Do I need approval to give a gift?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Are Facilitating Payments” to Public Officials allowed?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>is there approval needed for gifts to public officials?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Who is a public official?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>My client asked if her son can intern with the company as a favor to her, that isn't a problem is it?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>My friend works for the client, does that mean I can't give her a gift?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Is there certain criteria for gifts and entertainment&nbsp;</li>
        <li>How do I know if Gift or Entertainment is permissible?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>can I give gift cards to my team?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Do I need approval to give a gift?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Are Facilitating Payments” to Public Officials allowed?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>is there approval needed for gifts to public officials?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Who is a public official?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>My client asked if her son can intern with the company as a favor to her, that isn't a problem is it?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>My friend works for the client, does that mean I can't give her a gift?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Is there certain criteria for gifts and entertainment&nbsp;</li>
        <li>How do I know if Gift or Entertainment is permissible?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>can I give gift cards to my team?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Do I need approval to give a gift?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Are Facilitating Payments” to Public Officials allowed?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>is there approval needed for gifts to public officials?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Who is a public official?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>My client asked if her son can intern with the company as a favor to her, that isn't a problem is it?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>My friend works for the client, does that mean I can't give her a gift?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Is there certain criteria for gifts and entertainment&nbsp;</li>
        <li>How do I know if Gift or Entertainment is permissible?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>can I give gift cards to my team?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Do I need approval to give a gift?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Are Facilitating Payments” to Public Officials allowed?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>is there approval needed for gifts to public officials?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Who is a public official?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>My client asked if her son can intern with the company as a favor to her, that isn't a problem is it?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>My friend works for the client, does that mean I can't give her a gift?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Is there certain criteria for gifts and entertainment&nbsp;</li>
        <li>How do I know if Gift or Entertainment is permissible?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>can I give gift cards to my team?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Do I need approval to give a gift?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Are Facilitating Payments” to Public Officials allowed?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>is there approval needed for gifts to public officials?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Who is a public official?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>My client asked if her son can intern with the company as a favor to her, that isn't a problem is it?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>My friend works for the client, does that mean I can't give her a gift?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Is there certain criteria for gifts and entertainment&nbsp;</li>
        <li>How do I know if Gift or Entertainment is permissible?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>can I give gift cards to my team?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Do I need approval to give a gift?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Are Facilitating Payments” to Public Officials allowed?&nbsp;</li>
        <li>is there approval needed for gifts to public officials?&nbsp;</li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```